# $\int_{\alpha} \frac{z}{z^4-1}\ dz$ where $\alpha$ is a circle with center $a$, radius $a$, and $a>1$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I need to take the complex integral

$$\int_{\alpha} \frac{z}{z^4-1}\ dz$$

Over the circle with radius $a$ and center $a$, where $a>1$. Since the antiderivative of this integrand involves $\log$ and this isn t always analytic, specially if the circle touches the negative real axis, I can't just apply the theorem that says the integral is $0$ in the closed circle. Therefore, I need to integrate it using the Cauchy formula, but since the circle radius is variable, how do I identify which of the singularities $z=1,-1,i,-i$ can be used?

**Update**:

I was able to see how only the $z=1$ will be included in every contour, so that's what I did:

$$\int \frac{z}{(z^2-1)(z^2+1)}\ dz = \int \frac{z}{(z-1)(z+1)(z-1)(z+i)}\ dz$$

since only $z=1$ is included in the contour, we have by the Cauchy Integral Formula:

$$\int \frac{\frac{z}{(z+1)(z-i)(z+i)}}{(z-1)} = 2i\pi f(1)$$

where $$f = \frac{z}{(z+1)(z-i)(z+i)}\rightarrow f(1) = \frac{1}{2(1-i)(1+i)} = \frac{1}{4}$$

then:

$$\int \frac{\frac{z}{(z+1)(z-i)(z+i)}}{(z-1)} = \frac{i\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Make a sketch to see how it looks. It's then easy to see which of the singularities lie inside the circle.

Comment: Cauchy integral formula says that the value of the integral does not depend on the shape of the contour.  Only on the singularities inside.

Comment: That's correct. It's probably a little more convenient to leave the $z^2+1$ factor stand as is, and only factor $z^2-1$, but the difference is marginal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively:

Since $z=1$ is the only simple pole lying inside the contour, use $2πi\times\left[\frac{z}{\frac{d}{dz}(z^4-1)}\right]_{z=1}$

Comment: Use `\cdot` or `\times`, but don't use periods to indicate multiplication.

Comment: @Simple Art...thanks.